# add a deleteItemAtIndexPath for collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have been stuck all day on this.

i have my delegation set up properly. i have VC 1, where i am able to click a bar button item in top right corner to open VC 2.

In VC i am able to add a person's name and Photo and send the info back to VC 1, where the objects are placed into an array of collectionView cells.

Then, i have my DidSelectItemAtIndexPath method set up so when i click on the collectionViewCell. it segues to the same "+" screen (VC 2)

only this time it changes the title to "delete person" and programmatically adds a Trash button to the nav bar on the left.

When i click on the Trash button, it prints to the logs, "Person Deleted". **HERE IN LIES THE PROBLEM**

My protocol and Delegates are obviously correct if i am able to add and edit a persons image and name and save it permanently.

I cant for the life of me figure out how to add deleteItemAtIndexPath function to that Trash button i added in.

This is for Swift, and if someone can give me what i am missing i would be really appreciative. everything works fine but i can't figure out how to structure that trash button so it removes the selected item.

THANK YOU!

```
import UIKit

protocol AddNewTrainerViewControllerDelegate: class 
{
     func addNewTrainerViewControllerDidCancel(controller: AddNewTrainerViewController)
     func addNewTrainerViewController(controller: AddNewTrainerViewController, didFinishAddingItem item: TrainerArray)
     func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
     func addNewTrainerViewController(controller: AddNewTrainerViewController, didFinishEditingItem trainer: TrainerArray)
}

class AddNewTrainerViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBAction func openPhotoLibrary(sender: AnyObject) {

    var photoPicker = UIImagePickerController()
    photoPicker.delegate = self
    photoPicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    photoPicker.allowsEditing = true 
    self.presentViewController(photoPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBOutlet weak var trainerPhoto: UIImageView!

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    trainerPhoto.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let trainer = trainerToEdit {

        title = "Edit Trainer"
        textField.text = trainer.name
        trainerPhoto.image = trainer.trainerImage
        doneBarButton.enabled = true

        let deleteButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Trash, target: self, action: "deleteButton")
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = deleteButton
    }
}

func deleteButton() {
    print("Trainer Deleted")
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}

//outlet for done bar button item to control status
@IBOutlet weak var doneBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let oldText: NSString = textField.text!
    let newText: NSString = oldText.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    if newText.length > 3 {
        doneBarButton.enabled = true
    } else {
        doneBarButton.enabled = false
    }

   return true
}

//Trainer Name Text Field
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

//action outlet for done button
@IBAction func doneButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    if let trainer = trainerToEdit {

        trainer.name = textField.text!
        trainer.trainerImage = trainerPhoto.image!
        delegate?.addNewTrainerViewController(self, didFinishEditingItem: trainer)

    } else if trainerPhoto.image == nil {
        displayAlert("Please Add Your Trainer's Photo", message: "")

    } else if trainerPhoto.image != nil {

    let item = TrainerArray()
    item.name = textField.text!
    item.trainerImage = trainerPhoto.image!
    delegate?.addNewTrainerViewController(self, didFinishAddingItem: item)

    }

}

//action outlet for cancel or back button
@IBAction func cancelButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    delegate?.addNewTrainerViewControllerDidCancel(self)
}

// doesn't allow selection of the row. Won't turn gray.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {

    return nil
}

weak var delegate: AddNewTrainerViewControllerDelegate?

func displayAlert (title: String, message: String) {

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


}

var trainerToEdit: TrainerArray?
}
```

That is the code from VC 2. where the delete button is.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Ok give me about 1 min and i will get it up.

Answer (score 0):

1. add a protocol method for deletion in your delegate:

   ```
   func addNewTrainerViewControllerDidCHooseDelete(controller: AddNewTrainerViewController)
   ```
2. in your `deleteButton()` on VC2 implement call to the delegate method above.
3. in VC1, implement the delegate method above, find out the correct cell the same way as you implemented in `func addNewTrainerViewController(controller: AddNewTrainerViewController, didFinishEditingItem trainer: TrainerArray)`
   . Then delete the cell & dimiss VC2 the same way as edit Trainer.

Comment: Gah!! everything seems to be hooked up except i cannot find the call for the delete cell function for a collection view

Comment: i am doing collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPath()... but this just keeps giving me an error "Can not convert [such and such] to a value of type NSIndexPath. gives me this error no matter what i plug in as a parameter! help please

Comment: You should find out the correct NSIndexPath the same way you do in EditingItem and update the image on your collection view, then put it in an array for deleteItemsAtIndexPaths - which requires an Array of NSIndexPath as parameter